# selenium can't submit form

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm new to selenium and trying to automate the download of some government data. When using the code below. I manage to navigate to the right page and enter the right parmeter in the form, but then can't find a way to click the 'submit' button. I've tried `find_element_by_partial_link_text("Subm").click()` and I've tried `find_element_by_class_name` on a number of class names. Nothing works. Any ideas?

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
main_url="http://data.stats.gov.cn/english/easyquery.htm?cn=E0101"    
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get(main_url)
time.sleep(8)
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Industry").click()
time.sleep(8)
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Main Economic Indicat").click()
time.sleep(8)
driver.find_element_by_id("mySelect_sj").click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("dtText").send_keys("last72")
time.sleep(4)
try:
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("dtFoot").click()
except:
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("dtFoot").submit()
```

Comment: className is not unique so you must be more specific with the tag you want to click on for example: Xpath("//a[@class='dtFoot']").click();

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem, the key was using

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name(`dtTextBtn`)
```

instead of

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name(`dtTextBtn f10`)
```

The latter was what I saw in the source code, but the `f10` blocked selenium.